# terra::rast() vs raster::brick() for loading in .nc files

Tags: raster, r, terra

Long time `raster` user, first time using `terra`. I have a large .nc raster file (1,168 cells, 10,000 layers, 168MB in size).

When using `raster::brick()` the file is loaded into my R session within a second or two. When using `terra::rast()` the same file takes a very long time to load (45 mins and counting, so far)

Can someone explain (1) whether I'm using `terra` correctly to load in my .nc file and (2) what can account for the difference in speed?

I am using `raster` v3.4-13 and `terra` v1.3-22.

Comment: The docs for `rast` say, that like `raster`, it doesn't load the data into memory (just the basic metadata for the object) so it should be quick. Could you edit and add your version numbers of relative things? Has `terra:;rast` completed yet? Its possibly an infinite loop bug. Tried it on a smaller NetCDF?

Comment: That was my understanding of `rast()` too, @Spacedman. I ended up killing my R session in the end (after waiting well over an hour). I haven't tried on a smaller ncdf yet but will try that now and update my question once I have.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The difference is due to the large number of layers in your file (10,000). `raster` reads the CDF files with the `ncdf4` package. In contrast, `terra` reads all data with GDAL. That is convenient from a programming perspective, but GDAL is very inefficient in dealing with datasets with many layers. With ncdf4 there is just a third dimension (typically "time"), and it is not necessary to loop through all the layers as is the case with GDAL.

I expect this problem to disappear in a future version. Recent updates in GDAL provide alternative approaches that I want to explore in `terra`. Alternatively, I might not use GDAL for CDF files. Do not hold your breath. For now, it is better to use raster to read NetCDF files with many layers.

Comment: Hey @Robert, thanks very much for the explanation, appreciate the detailed response. I've continued using `raster` as you've suggested. I'll be sure to get stuck into `terra` with some other projects I'm working on which have far fewer layers!

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly recommend implementing most solutions using the `terra` package in the future, as the `raster` package has officially been superseded by the former.

Using an "outdated" solution would still be accpetable if it means that you get the program to work, as with the type of edge-case with large amount of layers that you described, but be aware that the `raster` might not continue to have full support for everything, and most actions would be safer to do using `terra`.